# Unable to copy file using Jenkins to an remote machine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to copy a war file from Jenkins sever to another linux machine. For that I have used SCP command. And also I have generated a private/public key.

When I copy a file (scp command) through putty it is happening without any error, but when I run my Jenkins file, where I have written shell script to copy the file to remote server using scp, it throws error saying "Permission denied (publickey,password)". Also I have configured Publish-over-SSH in my Jenkins and test-connection was successful.

```
stage 'War Copy'
node {
try{
    sh "scp /target/abc.war  user@remoteserver:/targetmachinefolder"
}catch(Exception e){
}
}
```

Comment: Are u logged in as jenkins user when you scp the war file?

Comment: No @afxentios. Could please tell me how to do.

Comment: `su - jenkins -s /bin/bash`